# Sonarqube - Remove this unused private field Code Smell using Lombok @data

Tags: java, sonarqube, lombok

I've got a bunch of Code Smells in my Java project around bits of code like this:

```
@Data
public class Foobar extends Foo { 
    private String baz;
}
```

My `lombok.config` sits alongside the `pom.xml` and looks like:

```
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

This brought up the code coverage numbers, not has not cleared the Code Smells.

Seems I'm not the [only](https://medium.com/@seesala.kiran/hi-the-above-solution-worked-for-me-well-wrt-code-coverage-c1df5e9ea571) person encountering this problem.

In terms of versions:

- Lombok 1.18.8 (also tried with 1.18.10)
- Jacoco 0.8.4
- SonarQube 7.9.1.27448
- SonarQube Scanner 4.0.0.1744

I've seen a few similar questions on this, but they are all ~5 years old, so I dont believe the answers are still valid.

Comment: discovered that the code smells are gone when running `mvn sonar:sonar`, not sure why.. but am going to do this rather than using sonar-scanner cli

Comment: was issue respolved:?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue with you a few months ago. My jacoco version is 0.8.2 and lombok is v1.16.16. I remember the problem was gone after I add lombok.config under root directory of the project.
Just notice if you define your own constructors for a class that already marked as Data, then the coverage will be calculated by how many constructors your tests were called.

And if this didn't help. You can find a workaround by excluding them in either Jacoco config / SonarQube config

Example for excluding in jacoco:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/your_class_path/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <!-- attached to Maven test phase -->
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And for SonarQube, you can use -Dsonar.inclusions parameter for inclusion and -Dsonar.exclusions parameter when calling mvn sonar:sonar

Comment: It's not Code Coverage (that is calculated correctly), it's Code Smells that I'm seeing issues with. I have a number of classes (and projects) that use this format, so don't really want to go down the route of excluding directories

Comment: If so, i think you can ignore that code smell by add sonar.issue.ignore property to your pom just for those classes.